# Почему появляется ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Почему появляется  ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
Пишу бот с регистрацией и бд и возникла ошибка

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Вот мой код

```py
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = None
        var = self.connection == sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execut("INSERT INTO `users` (users.users.user_id) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))


    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= ?", (user_id)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def set_nickname(self, user_id, nickname):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `nickname` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (nickname, user_id,))

    def get_signup(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `signup` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?",(user_id,)).fetchall()
            for row in result:
                signup = str(row[0])
            return signup
    def set_signup(self, user_id, signup):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `users` SET `signup` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?', (signup, user_id,))
```

Comment: `self.connection` у вас всегда равен None, а переменная `var` нигде не используется

Answer (score 0):

Должно все заработать если перепишите так:

```py
def __init__(self, db_file):
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```